# Extracting the titles of the websites mentioned in the link

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

https://www.g2.com/categories/marketing-automation

I am trying webscrap the above link that has list of 350+ websites i need to extract the title of the websites mentioned
But I am failing to get any results i have tried with using requests and beautiful soup
then with selenium and all i am getting is empty list "[]" or none

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Send a GET request to the URL and parse the HTML content
url = 'https://www.g2.com/categories/marketing-automation'
response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

name  = soup.find(class_ = "product-card__product-name")
print(name)
```

This above code is just a test code to check if the data is being pulled or not and the response is 'None'

From this code i am expecting to see the results of the class mentioned upon calling print

Comment: If you write `response` to a file, you'll probably see that it contains an error message instead of the expected content of the page. Your requests are being blocked for some reason. Maybe it's requests's User Agent, or maybe they're running something like reCAPTCHA v3 that tries to detect if the user is human. There might be a way around it, but circumventing the site's efforts to stop you from scraping also might be frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of got this code to get something. Im still working on it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the webpage
driver.get('https://www.g2.com/categories/marketing-automation')

# Wait for the page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Find all the product cards on the page
product_cards = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-card__product-name')

# Iterate over the product cards and extract the title from each one
for product_card in product_cards:
    title = product_card.text
    print(title)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Just need it to find the link